# Extend cNFTs with associated PDAs to store extra information

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

Currently i'm participating in the hackathon and my solana skills are quite limited.

My current stack mints cNFTs and i would like to create PDAs to store some extra information which it's not contained in the metadata and i can update.

Is it possible to do with cNFTs or do i need to migrate them to NFTs? Do you know any resource which can I use as a reference?

Thanks in advance!